# How to model a travelling pulley with multibody components

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I'm working to teach myself Modelica.  So far I have read all the available books, and I also downloaded Michael Tiller's excellent "Modelica By Example" code from github.  I wish there were more multibody examples available which use the standard multibody library found in, e.g., Dymola and OpenModelica.  I'm trying to learn how to use the multibody components by building a travelling pulley, that is to say a pulley that rotates in a non-inertial reference frame.  This is the kind of pulley that is used in a block and tackle, for example.  Such a pulley would have 3 connectors to arbitrary translational components and would probably make use of prismatic components with varying length.

Can anyone point me in the right direction concerning how to make the pulley in Modelica, or where I might find examples of similar multibody models?

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow .This is not email list. Its Q & A forum, you start trying something and then you face some issue. We will help you.

Comment: To be fair, he has a question.  It just turns out he asked it on an email list and I asked him to repost it here.  Just ignore the "on this email list".

Comment: I just edited this passage out, should appear soon.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue I see with modeling such a system using the `Multibody` library is the constraint of the rope.  If I were going to model such a system, I would work strictly from the kinematic relationships and how power is distributed by the system.  I wrote [a blog post](http://blog.xogeny.com/blog/imp-diff) a while back that goes through how to fuse together kinematics and power conservation into Modelica models.  I think a similar approach would probably work quite well in your case.

Comment: Could you write your blog post here because your blog is not available anymore. Web archive can help https://web.archive.org/web/20190317011535/http://blog.xogeny.com/blog/imp-diff/